# How come the answer is 5?

Tags: c++

I was browsing through Medium, and found this simple prroblem statement:

```
int i = 4;
int j = i++;
int k = ++j;
cout << i << j << k << endl;
//output:= i= 5, j=5, k= 5
```

how is that possible? Like if we are placing the i as 4, but output is 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post increment operation (i++) is always **assign, then increment**

Pre increment operation (++j) is always **increment, then assign**

So in your second line, i is first assigned to j, then i increases. So j has the original i value.

In your last statement, j is incremented first and then assigned to k.

Answer (score 5):

```cpp
int i = 4;     // Assigns the value 4 to i
int j = i++;   // Assigns i to j THEN INCREMENTS i; j is 4, i is 5
int k = ++j;   // INCREMENTS j THEN assigns j to k; j is 5, k is 5
```

Comment: Technically `j` is initialized, not assigned; and the increment of `i` must be completed before `j` receives its value

Comment: @M.M Technically, yes, But the results are as indicated.

Answer (score -3):

Because , when statement i++ is executed, i got 5;